# How do you apply the object transform so that scaling the object on a single axis actually scales along the correct axis?

Tags: transforms

I am trying to scale an object along the Y Axis (flipping it by -1) but I am having trouble. When I scale it by Y, it seems to be a semi-arbitrary axis. The 3D cursor shows that the object's orientation is not aligned with the world, but I want to scale it on the world's Y Axis. I've tried clearing and applying rotation but it doesn't seem to be doing what I expect. I would think that clear rotation would be what I'm looking for, but it doesn't seem to work. I want the object to stay in the same exact world location but I want its rotation to be 0,0,0. How can I zero the object's rotation without affecting its actual position/rotation?

Thanks,
Warren

Comment: Are you typing "S" then "Y" then "-1", "return" and not getting what you'd expect? That's strange, because scaling along an axis should **already use the world's - not the object's - axes** (unless you type "Y" twice). Can you provide some screenshots?

Comment: @NicolaSap - Yes, that's what is happening. The transform location and rotation are all set to 0's but the 3d Cursor shows a non-aligned set of axes. Seeing if this image post works: ![Image](http://i.imgur.com/kOGxHoa.png)

Comment: Oh, I see where it is -- Delta Transform... Now how do I apply that and zero it out?

Comment: I figured out one way to do it -- manually copy the delta transform rotation into the regular transform, then apply the rotation. Is there a better way?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how to reply. However I'd suggest you to edit your question with the new information that you've found, in order to get new and more relevant answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem I had was that the "Delta Transform" in the object properties contained rotation.

My solution was to:

1: Apply the rotation with CTRL-A (Should leave Transform at 0,0,0)
2: Copy Delta Transform's rotation values (x,y,z) to the Transform of the object.
3: Clear the Delta Transform (just set it to 0,0,0).

Now the delta transform is clear, and scaling will work in world space.

Comment: If there is a way to do this automatically (ie "Apply delta transform") please let me know.

Comment: It's possible [the other way around](https://docs.blender.org/manual/ko/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/clear_apply.html#transforms-to-deltas), converting transform to deltas (in Ctrl+A menu as of 2.78). One can clear deltas with Shift+Ctrl+action (R for rotate and so on). I'm not sure if you can copy them back to transforms and clear delta at once.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

[image]
Please try this : in Object mode, hit Ctrl + A, in resulting menu select **Rotation**

[image]

Its all zero now, I hope it help you :) best of luck

Comment: Hi @BlenderForYou, thanks for your response. I would have expected that to work, but it does not unfortunately. Somewhere there must be a hidden transform that is not being applied. :/

Comment: Did it fixed the rotations to zeros?

Comment: It fixed the rotations to 0's, but my problem was that there was rotation in the "Delta Transform" in the object properties, which I didn't know existed.