# Applying Scale makes object smaller

Tags: transforms

I'm modelling a basic shape and after I finish my model I wanted to apply the scale before saving it. Problem is when I CTRL+A and apply scale my model gets smaller. Applying it the second time makes it even smaller. Changing dimensions of the object on the transform panel totally freaks the model by scaling it.
I am uploading three images show the situation. I just applied scale between taking another screenshot.

Any advice or help would be great. Thank you in advance.

[image: Image1-Original]

[image: Image2-FirstApplyScale]

[image: Image3-Second-ApplyScale]

Comment: Looks like you have Delta Scale changed from 1 to something else (Properties editor > Object tab > Delta Transform). After applying scale try returning it to 1, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/87629/1245

Comment: @MrZak Thank you. It was my mistake. I corrected it to 1 and it is working now.